# Strokes appearing on my logo in the browser when no stroke colour has been set on the SVG in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export, svg, stroke

First of all please forgive my lack of experience in illustrator, I've just started out and am therefore a complete novice in design.

I've just created my logo, saved and exported it as an SVG. It appears how I want it in Illustrator with just colour fills and no strokes, but in the browser a light stroke colour is being applied to each path. I used the live paint bucket tool to fill in the different shapes with different shades. Anyone know what I've done wrong here?

[image: Logo with unwanted stroke colour]

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the svg code exported from Illustrator? Most of the time you'll see something along the lines of `.st0{fill:none;stroke:#BD4931;stroke-width:4;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;}` or similar.

If you delete the `stroke:#______` and `stroke-width:_`, no strokes or outlines will appear.